# how to read a line in discord

Tags: python, discord

I am writing a bot for discord and there is a command ($ bone) in which the bot writes the following: "select a number from 1 - 9" and after that the user should answer and here's how I can read the line in which he wrote the number?

Comment: What do you mean by "the line"? What have you tried so far? How does your current code look like?

Comment: a line in which the user will write any number from 1 to 9

Comment: you want  `wait_for_message` https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#waiting-for-events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As alluded to in the comments, we will use a coroutine called wait_for, that waits for events like `message`: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for

Because these are the same events we might hook into with `bot.event`, we will be able to process the returned message.

```py
@bot.command()
async def bone(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Select a number 1-9")
    
    def my_check_func(message): #A checking function: When we return True, consider our message "passed".
        if message.author == ctx.author: #Make sure we're only responding to the original invoker
            return True
        else:
            return False

    response = await bot.wait_for("message", check=my_check_func) #This waits for the first message event that passes the check function.
    #This execution process now freezes until a message that passes that check is sent,
    #but other bot interactions can still happen.
    c = response.content #equal to message.content, because response IS a message
    if c.isdigit() and 1 <= int(c) <= 9: #if our response is a number equal to 1, 9, or between those...
        await ctx.send("You sent: {}".format(response.content))
    else:
        await ctx.send("That's not a number between 1 and 9!")
```

Real example interaction to prove it works:

```
Cook1
$bone

Tutbot
Select a number 1-9
Cook1
4

Tutbot
You sent: 4

Cook1
$bone

Tutbot
Select a number 1-9

Cook1
no

Tutbot
That's not a number between 1 and 9!
```